# how to pass std::stringstream with raw data from C++ to Python using Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython, pybind11, cythonize

C++ code:

```
char* SendData()
{
  std::stringstream ofs;
  FillData(ofs); // this is actually copy some serialized npy data into the stream which has nulls i.e. /0 in middle
  const std::string my_str = ofs.str();
  auto len = my_str.length();
  char* cstr = new char[len-1];
  strcpy(cstr, my_str.c_str()); // I believe after /0 it is losing data
  return cstr;
}
```

in cython .pyx:

```
  def send_data(self):
    return self.cpp_api.SendData()
```

in Python side:

```
result = self.python_api.send_data() #send_data is mapped to SendData in cython .pyx
load_bytes = BytesIO(result)
arr =  np.load(load_bytes, allow_pickle=True)
```

But before data reach python code, i believe i am losing the data due to \0.
In C++ code, if i print my_str, it will print entire array:

```
\ufffdNUMPY\x01\x00F\x00{'descr': '<f4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3, 4, 5), }       \n";\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd&\r\ufffd\x1blx\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\x11\ufffd''y\ufffdG\ufffd\x07\ufffd\t\ufffd"\ufffdN\ufffd3\ufffdm\ufffd\x08\ufffd\u02fb-\ufffd@cz
```

if i print cstr it print only:

```
\ufffdNUMPY\x01
```

And eventually python code is receiving the same partial data.

Comment: `strcpy` will, indeed, stop copying when it reaches a null character. You can't use string handling functions on things that are not strings.

Comment: going on a whim here, but do you really need to use `strcpy`? why not use `memcpy`, `std::copy_n` or simiar? since you know there can be `\0`s. most of the `str*` functions have this property of stopping at `\0`

Comment: Your problem is the interface: how the python should know how long the string is? It will stop at first 0. So you will have to change the interface to also return the length of the string.

Comment: @ben10 std::copy_n worked on the c++ side.
But issue persist on Python side where we read.
As ead mentioned, I might need to pass length as well.
Assuming I have the length, now how to read buffer of length '20' in python's BytesIO?

Comment: Are you using pybind11 for cpp_api? Or is it pure cython?